# Investigating properties of complements of paths

Tags: graph-theory

Take the first $n$ natural numbers. Construct a vertex-labeled graph with a vertex for each number. Now, connect any two vertices $a,b$ with an edge iff $a \pm 1 \neq b$.

As [*Perry Iverson*](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/999973/186298) pointed out, these graphs are complements of paths on $n$ vertices.

> I computed some graphs.
>
> [4 vertices, 3 edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9SCm.png); [5 vertices, 6 edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFtss.png); [6 vertices, 10 edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXZE0.png)

I am interested in how the number of edges grows.

Any help is appreciated as always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vertex labeled $i$, where $i$ is different from $1$ and $n$ is adjacent to all other vertices except $i-1$ and $i+1$, so it has degree $n-3$. The vertices labeled $1$ and $n$ are adjacent to all but one other vertex, so they have degree $n-2$. This means the total number of edges is:

$$\frac{1}{2}((n-2)(n-3) + 2(n-2)) = \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$$

Another way to think of this is that your graph is the complement of a path on $n$ vertices. So the total number of edges must be:

$$\binom{n}{2} - (n-1) = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} - (n-1) = \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$$